# Challenge with automatically populating a grid/table

Tags: swiftui

I have an array of words which I would like to summarise by starting letter and sorted by length of word in a grid/table as follows:

- Top row is a heading for columns
- Left column is a heading for rows
- Columns are starting letters of words
- Rows are length of words
- Trailing column is the sum of rows
- Bottom row is the sum of columns

Example of what I’d like to achieve:
[what I'd like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caban.png)

The array of words changes often; unique starting letters can be any letter from the alphabet (but always only 3 different letters for each array) and length of words can range from 4 to 15 characters.

My challenge is so far my code is cumbersome and “inelegant” but most importantly does not work where a grid value is nil. I should perhaps be building a dictionary of the data and using that to populate the grid, but not entirely sure how to do that. Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Results of my attempt so far:
[attempt so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfjpU.png)

My MRE is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let words: [String] = ["deed", "denote", "donut", "eden", "ended", "heeded", "hood"]
    let letters = Array(" " + "DEH" + " ")
    
    var body: some View {
        let wordsByLength = Dictionary.init(grouping: words, by: \.count).mapValues(\.count).sorted(by: <)
        Form {
            HStack(spacing: 5) {
                ForEach(letters, id: \.self) { position in
                    Text(position.description).bold()
                        .frame(minWidth: 30, maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
            HStack(spacing: 5)  {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(wordsByLength.sorted(by: <), id: \.key) { key, value in
                        Text(key.description).bold()
                    }
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 30, maxWidth: .infinity)
                VStack {
                    ForEach(Dictionary.init(grouping: words.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(letters[1].lowercased().description)}), by: \.count).mapValues(\.count).sorted(by: <), id: \.key) { key, value in
                        Text(value.description)
                    }
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 30, maxWidth: .infinity)
                VStack {
                    ForEach(Dictionary.init(grouping: words.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(letters[2].lowercased().description)}), by: \.count).mapValues(\.count).sorted(by: <), id: \.key) { key, value in
                        Text(value.description).foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 30, maxWidth: .infinity)
                VStack {
                    ForEach(Dictionary.init(grouping: words.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(letters[3].lowercased().description)}), by: \.count).mapValues(\.count).sorted(by: <), id: \.key) { key, value in
                        Text(value.description).foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 30, maxWidth: .infinity)
                VStack {
                    ForEach( Dictionary.init(grouping: words, by: \.count).mapValues(\.count).sorted(by: <), id: \.key) { key, value in
                        Text(value.description).bold()
                    }
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 30, maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Grid` and `GridRow`?

Comment: You could check out LazyHGrid/LazyVGrid and GridItem, I have used it to create matrices similar to what you are trying to achieve
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/griditem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple!

If you were in my team and I saw code like:

```
Dictionary.init(grouping: words.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(letters[1].lowercased().description)}), by: \.count).mapValues(\.count).sorted(by: <), id: \.key)
```

I'd (politely) ask you to think how you could simplify it. There's zero chance you would look at that code in 6 months time and understand what it did.

Think about what each cell contains:

- Top Row:

  - starting letters of the words
- Next rows:

  - lengths of the words
  - number of words for each starting letter and length
  - count of words with length
- Bottom Row

  - count of words for each starting letter

Now we understand what goes in each square, we can write functions for each, i.e.:

```
var initialLetters: [String] {
    Set(words.compactMap(\.first).map { String($0) }).sorted(by: <)
}

var wordLengths: [Int] {
    Set(words.map(\.count)).sorted(by: <)
}

func countOfWordsStartingWith(_ string: String, length: Int) -> Int {
    words.filter { $0.hasPrefix(string)}.filter { $0.count == length }.count
}

func countOfWordsLength(_ length: Int) -> Int {
    words.filter { $0.count == length }.count
}

func countOfWordsStartingWith(_ string: String) -> Int {
    words.filter { $0.hasPrefix(string)}.count
}
```

Then your view becomes:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let words = ["deed", "denote", "donut", "eden", "ended", "heeded", "hood"]
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Grid {
                GridRow {
                    Color.clear // Used to fill empty spaces in the Grid
                        .frame(width: 1, height: 1)
                    ForEach(initialLetters, id: \.self) { letter in
                        Text(letter.uppercased())
                            .bold()
                    }
                    
                    Color.clear
                        .frame(width: 1, height: 1)
                }
         
                Divider()
                ForEach(wordLengths, id: \.self) { wordLength in
                    
                    GridRow {
                        Text(wordLength, format: .number)
                            .bold()
                        
                        ForEach(initialLetters, id: \.self) { letter in
                            Text(countOfWordsStartingWith(letter, length: wordLength), format: .number)
                        }
                        Text(countOfWordsLength(wordLength), format: .number)
                            .italic()
                    }
                    Divider()
                }
                
                GridRow {
                    Color.clear
                        .frame(width: 1, height: 1)
                    ForEach(initialLetters, id: \.self) { letter in
                        Text(countOfWordsStartingWith(letter), format: .number)
                            .italic()
                    }
                    Color.clear
                        .frame(width: 1, height: 1)
                }
                
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
```

[image]

Note how this now only has one "source of truth" (`words`), so no need for a separate array of letters.

It's also dynamic, so it works whatever you add to the words:

```
let words = ["whatever", "deed", "denote", "donut", "eden", "ended", "heeded", "hood"]
```

[image]

Comment: Keep it simple, noted! And thanks for the very clear way of breaking it all down into the key components - very elegant code and certainly not the cumbersome mess I started with. On with learning and improving. Thanks! :)